# How to avoid Cusps and Corners when generating spline?

Tags: mobile-robot, motion-planning, trajectory

[Here](https://github.com/GPrathap/motion_planning/blob/main/motion_planning_alg/scripts/cubic_spline_trajectory_generator.py#enroll-beta) I wrote Qubic spline trajectory generation. The following are the result.

**Spline that generated**
[image]

**Curvature of the spline**
[image]

**Yaw angle changes**
[image]

According to Figure 02, there is a sharp change in yaw angle, i.e., between 40 to 45 alone x-axis and the corresponding location of the trajectory is shown in blue in Figure 01.

**Question:**

**Is there a way to overcome such student changes when generating spline?**

Comment: Is it really a sharp change? The so-called sharp change is caused by the angle wrapping - the yaw angle is wrapped between -180, and 180 degrees. Since the trajectory starts moving upwards in the y-axis the yaw angle becomes positive.

Comment: so robot heading angle will rotate quickly

Comment: You could use the gsplines library to get minimum jerk/acceleraion/etc splines https://github.com/rafaelrojasmiliani/gsplines_cpp/